# Split a String into 2 Variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, substring

I am wanting to convert a string into 2 variables..

I have created a variable and I am using substring to split it, however I can't seem to get it working.

If I create a alert message it display's the orignal variable that I want split up (so I know there is something there)

My code looks like this:

```
// variable 'ca' is set from a XML Element Response
alert(ca); // displays a string (eg. 123456789) - which does display fine
alert(ca.substring(0,1));  // should alert 1 but it stops and nothing is displayed
```

but I add **ca = "123456789";** as below, it works..

```
ca = "123456789";
alert(ca); // displays a string (eg. 123456789) - which does display fine
alert(ca.substring(0,1));  // should alert 1 but it stops and nothing is displayed
```

however the variable ca has something set and is display right before the substring is used..

anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: If I have to guess maybe you're looking for `ca` value while ajax call is still running... could you post the relevant code please?

Comment: Your xml response might have some spaces at the beginning. Try - `alert('>>' + ca.substring(0,1) + '<<' );`

Comment: Please tell me you have checked for errors on the page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable doesn't contain a string, it contains something else, probably a number.

Convert the value to a string, to be able to use string methods on it:

```
ca = ca.toString();
```

Comment: You where spot on, it was a number and I needed to convert it to a string. - Your a life saver.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `ca` doesn't contain a string but a number.
Does it work when you cast the variable to a string?

```
alert(String(ca).substring(0,1));
```

(Note that you can check what a variable contains with the `typeof` operator:

```
console.log(typeof ca);
// number
console.log(typeof String(ca));
// string
```

UPDATE: both `ca.toString()` and `String(ca)` should work, but I personally prefer `String(ca)` since that will also work if ca is `null` or `undefined`.